# Milvus 2.2.8 stuck at create_index, why?

Tags: milvus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeLnD.jpg)

How should I solve it？

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to have more context, ie the rest of the code block as well as the output and/or the error message you're seeing. From what I can tell, I think changing `self.milvus.flush_()` to `self.milvus.flush()` might help fix it